# How to display null text field in TemplateField in Gridview with asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to display null text field in TemplateField in Gridview with asp.net c#?
Thank in Advance

Comment: You might consider adding more information. This is very vague.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try _anything_ to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 0):

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>No records listed</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

or maybe

```
gv.DataSource = string.Empty;
gv.DataSource.DataBind();
```

Comment: -im saying particuler ex:<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="1%" HeaderText="Grand" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblamount1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("total_amt").ToString()%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate></asp:templatefield> can u tell me how we can set label null value ?Thank in advance